# How to configure rollup with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollupjs

I am working on project using `Vue.js`, bundling with Rollup.

Here is my `rollup.config.js` file

```
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue2'
import less from 'rollup-plugin-less2';
import buble from 'rollup-plugin-buble'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload'
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve'

const plugins = [
    vue({'css':'none'}),
    less({output: "dist/build.css"}),
    buble({exclude: 'node_modules/**'}),
    nodeResolve({browser: true, jsnext: true}),
    commonjs()
]

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    plugins.push(uglify())
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    plugins.push(livereload('dist'))
    plugins.push(serve({
        contentBase: "",
        open: true
    }))
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/build.js',
        format: 'iife',
        sourcemap: true,
        //external: ["vue","vue-router"],
    },
    //external: ["vue","vue-router"],
    plugins
}
```

Here is my `main.js` file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Foo = {template: '<div>foo</div>'}
const Bar = {template: '<div>bar</div>'}

const routes = [
    {path: '/foo', component: Foo},
    {path: '/bar', component: Bar}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

var app = new Vue({
    router: router,
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

I have this error after running my project

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

If I use Vue as external lib and uncomment this `["vue","vue-router"], external: ["vue","vue-router"]` all working fine.

How to make my project compile and work with `rollup`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Found a solution here: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/487

You have to use the rollup replace plugin to replace all calls to process.env.NODE_ENV in all imported files like so:

```
plugins: [
  replace({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'production' )
  })
]
```

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify( 'production' )`? Just write `'"production"'`

Comment: This string would be saved in the source code instead of being dynamically edited, so it's safer